# Magento 2 : How to get product info on shipping model?

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, shipping, model

I was working on shipping method to remove some method based on product attribute. I've used preference for shipping model class `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping`

this is code of that class.

```
public function collectCarrierRates($carrierCode, $request)
    {

        $carrier = $this->_carrierFactory->createIfActive($carrierCode, $request->getStoreId());
        if (!$carrier) {
            return $this;
        }

        //unset other method if cart has speific product attribute
        if($carrierCode=="flatrate"):
            return $this;
         endif;

        $carrier->setActiveFlag($this->_availabilityConfigField);
        $result = $carrier->checkAvailableShipCountries($request);
        if (false !== $result && !$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
            $result = $carrier->proccessAdditionalValidation($request);
        }
        /*
         * Result will be false if the admin set not to show the shipping module
         * if the delivery country is not within specific countries
         */
        if (false !== $result) {
            if (!$result instanceof \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Error) {
                if ($carrier->getConfigData('shipment_requesttype')) {
                    $packages = $this->composePackagesForCarrier($carrier, $request);
                    if (!empty($packages)) {
                        $sumResults = [];
                        foreach ($packages as $weight => $packageCount) {
                            $request->setPackageWeight($weight);
                            $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                            if (!$result) {
                                return $this;
                            } else {
                                $result->updateRatePrice($packageCount);
                            }
                            $sumResults[] = $result;
                        }
                        if (!empty($sumResults) && count($sumResults) > 1) {
                            $result = [];
                            foreach ($sumResults as $res) {
                                if (empty($result)) {
                                    $result = $res;
                                    continue;
                                }
                                foreach ($res->getAllRates() as $method) {
                                    foreach ($result->getAllRates() as $resultMethod) {
                                        if ($method->getMethod() == $resultMethod->getMethod()) {
                                            $resultMethod->setPrice($method->getPrice() + $resultMethod->getPrice());
                                            continue;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                    }
                } else {
                    $result = $carrier->collectRates($request);
                }
                if (!$result) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
            if ($carrier->getConfigData('showmethod') == 0 && $result->getError()) {
                return $this;
            }
            // sort rates by price
            if (method_exists($result, 'sortRatesByPrice') && is_callable([$result, 'sortRatesByPrice'])) {
                $result->sortRatesByPrice();
            }
            $this->getResult()->append($result);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I'm trying to get product info here, but I am not able to get it. 
Anybody has idea how to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following way:

```
if ($request->getAllItems()) {
    foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $item->getProduct()->getSku();
    }
}
```

[For more detail](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php#L103)

Comment: Great. I dont know why but it was not works when i used same. strange but its work now